# Do you need to have wifi for your application to get results with RedLaser SDK?

Tags: iphone, barcode-scanner

I'm currently developing an application to scan for a barcode, give a description of the product (local database) and provide a movie as a way of providing a user manual. My only question is does the scanning feature of the redlaser sdk require me to be on wifi? Or do the results of scanning just come up locally through some sort of algorithm in the redlaser sdk.

I've searched their forums but found nothing of this kind. And before I buy myself a developers account for their product, I would like to know this :)

Thanks in advance.

Lewion

Answer (score 0):

How about asking that question their support? :)

Also, test it for yourself - turn iPhone to Airplane mode (no wifi or 2g/3g), launch RedLaser app and scan a barcode - can it recognize it? It my experience, yes - it can read the UPC (but can't fetch any info/price for it of course - since there is no inet connection).

If i remember, initially their app had to actually upload the photo to their servers for recognition but since then they improved it and now recognize the 1D barcode in the app/SDK